# Difference between "Between" and "X1 <= Y <= X2"

Tags: sql

What is the difference between the following two SQL queries:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM df_1 AS a
LEFT JOIN df_2 AS b
ON a.id = b.id
AND a.datadate between b.sdate and b.edate;

SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM df_1 AS a
LEFT JOIN df_2 AS b
ON a.id = b.id
AND b.sdate <= a.datadate <= b.edate;
```

The latter statement does not give me the desired output. I.e. there exist rows in which a.datadate does not lie between b.sdate and e.edate. The former statement does give me the desired output.

Conceptually I would have thought the two statements are equal to each other. Apparently, I am wrong. What is the difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid SQL:

```
AND b.sdate <= a.datadate <= b.edate
```

The reason is that it is parsed as:

```
AND (b.sdate <= a.datadate) <= b.edate
```

And a boolean expression is not really appropriate for the `<=`.  Some databases (ahem, MySQL) will implicitly convert booleans to numbers.  And then implicitly convert those numbers back to dates.  So, the comparison would be to whatever date value corresponds to `0` and `1` in those cases.

So, the summary is that this would be a syntax error in most databases.  And probably produce incomprehensible results where the syntax is supported.

I should note that there might be some SQL systems that do support this syntax.  I think SAS proc SQL does, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I am familiar with SAS proc SQL, hence probably thought that this is valid syntax. This cleared it up for me!